# Quero mudar o tamanho do meu slideshow conforme muda o tamanho do dispositivo;

Tags: javascript

O HTML do meu slide show é esse quero que mude o `style="width"` toda vez que mude o tamanho do dispositivo.

```
<div class="leftside">
    <div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshowarea">
            <div class="slide">.</div>
            <div class="slide">.</div>
            <div class="slide">.</div>
            <div class="slide">.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O *CSS*

```
.slideshow{
     height: 335px;
     background-color: #CCC;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshowarea{
    width: 100000px;
    height: 335px;
    background-color: #DDD;
}

.slide{
    height: 335px;
    float: left;
}
```

Fis esse script pra pegar a largura e depois definir em todos os slides mas esta me retornando erro;

```
window.onload = function() {


    var slidewidth = document.getElementById('slideshow').offsetWidth;
    var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");


    for (var i in objs) {
        objs[i].style.width = slidewidth;

    }
}
```

Mas está me retornando esse erro :

```
script.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined at window.onload (script.js:9) window.onload @ script.js:9
```

Sou iniciante na área, já procurei e já tentei bastante sobre isso, espero que possam me ajudar, ta complicado o negocio.

Comment: Vlw pessoal pelas resposta consegui resolver colocando ..
if(!isNaN(i)) objs[i].style.width = slidewidth+"px"; bora estudar mais sobre o assunto;;

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza `for..in`, ele vai interagir somente com as propriedades enumeradas, como `getElementsByClassName` retorna um *HTMLCollection* que herda propriedades não enumeradas de object.prototype e String.prototype.

> `for...in` não deve ser usado para iteração em uma Array onde a ordem é importante, visto que ele interage em uma ordem arbitrária.

Já o `for..of`, ele cria um `loop` com os valores de objetos do tipo `Iterator` (`HTMLCollection`, `Array`, `NodeList`, `FileList` etc.)

**Exemplo:**

```js
const itens = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

for (let item in itens) {
  console.log( item )
}

console.log( "" );
console.log( "Agora com for..of" );
console.log( "" );

for (let item of itens) {
  console.log( item )
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item #1</li>
  <li>Item #2</li>
  <li>Item #3</li>
  <li>Item #4</li>
  <li>Item #5</li>
</ul>
```

---

Para capturar qualquer alteração quando houver uma mudança no tamanho da tela, basta usar o evento `resize`.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  console.log(" Houve uma mudança ");
}, false);

console.log( "Clique no item \"Página toda\"" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Como só lhe interessa os índices da coleção, pode incluir um `if` verificando se o valor retornado do `for` é um número. Apenas adicione `if(!isNaN(i))` antes do 
`objs[i].style.width = slidewidth+"px";`.

> Outra coisa, faltou adicionar `px` ao estilo `width`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var slidewidth = document.getElementById('slideshow').offsetWidth;
    var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

    for (var i in objs) {
       if(!isNaN(i)) objs[i].style.width = slidewidth+"px";
    }
}
```

```css
.slideshow{
 height: 335px;
 background-color: #CCC;
 overflow: hidden;
  }

.slideshowarea{
 width: 100000px;
 height: 335px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.slide{
height: 335px;
float: left;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftside">
    <div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshowarea">
            <div class="slide">.</div>
            <div class="slide">.</div>
            <div class="slide">.</div>
            <div class="slide">.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```